# Fail2ban not resulting in any update of IPTables

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, vps, fail2ban

I have:

1. Installed Fail2ban
2. Created a local jail file.
3. Changed lines within `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` where enabled is mentioned x2 to true.
4. Added `enabled = true` to the Asterisk section of the jail.local file.
5. Increased ban time to 1 day.

I'm running FreePBX on an Ubuntu VPS (they do not allow ISOs to be uploaded on my plan) so I do not benefit from the built-in protection that comes with the ISO. The only instructions that I could find were for Ubuntu and not CentOS so that is where I am.

A visit to #networking on Libera chat was not helpful.

One thing that was identified though was that iptables should, as the result of fail2ban being installed, configured and running correctly, be populated.

```
sudo iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 13837 packets, 1446K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 13835 packets, 1134K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

so empty.

Comment: you ran `service fail2ban restart`?

Comment: Did you see this post on a simialr issue? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438019/cant-list-any-iptables-rules-with-iptables-lvn

Comment: Hi, thanks, yes I ran service fail2ban restart but it hasn't made any difference. The link shows nothing other than the same empty rules list.